# Android profiling export memory graph data

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling

I would need to export the values (x, y) related to the android studio profiling memory graph to be later analyze in an excel sheet and use in a latex document to replicate the graphs.
I couldn't find a setting from where I can export the values of the graphs, is there a way to do it?

I add an example below of the memory graph, to which I would like to obtain the data (x,y) to be able to reproduce it on excel.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Could you please provide some additional information on tools you used? What version of android studio, how to get profile? Can you upload you profile files to the internet?

Comment: I use the last version of android studio. I would export generated on memory profiling, because I need to insert it inside on a document, reporting the memory usage. Is there a possibility to export the data that generates the graph?